# App has been flagged for GCM SDK usage even though we no longer use GCM SDK

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

Recently, we received an email informing us that our app is impacted by the deprecation of GCM:

```
Your Firebase project(s) that use Firebase Cloud Messaging APIs are listed below:
App-Name(XXXXXX)
Your recent usage of impacted APIs/features: GCM SDK
```

However, we have long migrated from GCM to FCM. In fact, the latest FCM SDK version that our app uses in production is 23.0.0. I have also verified that our app dependencies do not utilize GCM.[image]

I'd like to ask why our app has been flagged even though we have already migrated from GCM to FCM? Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Don’t you have older versions out in the wild?

Comment: hmmm yeah looks like there are still a few users attempting to use old versions of our app. However, it's likely that the app will shut down on launch, and I don't think it will even reach the point of calling GCM functions

Comment: I'm also at a loss, we have an Android and an iOS app in our project, none of them use GCM but still got the email warning us about its usage. I'd appreciate an update if you found anything. I'll be doing the same.

Comment: I contacted Firebase and they said that if we're using FCM in our apps, we can ignore the notice. The alert might be for someone with an old app version. Since we've already switched to FCM a while back, our setup should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Firebase and they said that if we're using FCM in our apps, we can ignore the notice. The alert might be for outlier user with an old app version. Since we've already switched to FCM a while back, our setup should be fine.